# Matplotlib contourf - Input z must be at least a 2x2 array?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

I am using `contourf` to plot 3 points. The x values are (.5, 1.25, 1.75) and the y values are (1,1,1).

I have my 3 z points to go along with this. So, I made:

```
xlist = [[.5],        [1.25],      [1.75]       ]  
ylist = [[1],         [1],         [1]          ] 
zlist = [[11.09856186][10.82105586][ 9.73936149]]
```

However, when I run this, I get the error:

> zlist must be at least a 2x2 array.

Does this mean I must graph at least 4 points?

Comment: You cannot draw a contour with 3 points... even when doing it by hand. Maybe you want to desribe a bit more in detail what you want to do and how the plot is supposed to look like.

Comment: Hey thanks, okay so basically I have 3 points that I know the values of a function for and I want to recreate the contour map for that function as best I can using only those 3 points.

Comment: and what is the minimum number of points you need to draw a contour by hand? 4?

Comment: Ok, so by hand it would work, if all x and y are different from each other. You could do the same with matplotlib's `tricontour`, but for y all being the same number, no contour can be defined mathematically. (Or maybe one could define it in the sense of "contour points" instead of contour lines, but I suppose that is not what you want).

Comment: ahh okay that does make sense, so if the ys are defined at the same value, even if the xs are defined differently, you cannot make a contour plot?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I aligned the 3 lists, do you notice anything?  The syntax used for x and y does not match z.  zlist is missing the `,` between elements...  So it is not a list per say, hence the error.